# how to save date in IST format on server

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

heys  guys,
i want to store the date in IST format in sql server 2008, my issue is i have an error log table, whenever there is any problem in my website, it save the entry in database, now what i want to do is, i want to store the date in IST format, so that i can come to know the occurance of the error if my client complains for any.. but i dont get an option to convert date in IST format before saving in sqlserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates (datetimes) are stored as binary; the format is only an issue when you display (or output) a date  as text.

You can format a date using [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Also see:

- [Date and Time Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) (TSQL)
- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) (.NET)
- [String Formatting in C#](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/)

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you tell me is there anything i can do in .net to change the time format from EST to IST, i know its against my question within the thread, but can you please help me. i needed this done urgently.

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797/effectively-converting-dates-between-utc-and-local-ie-pst-time-in-sql-2005#25073