# Data transfer between SQL Servers in different timezones

Tags: sql-server, timezone

I transfer data from one SQL Server to another using `SELECT * INTO ....` statement (in Management Studio). Both databases have different timezone settings.

Is it possible to adjust all date/time fields to different timezone automatically? Maybe some query parameters or connection settings?

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server?? With **SQL Server 2008**, you get the `DATETIMEOFFSET` datatype, and the `SWITCHOFFSET` function to convert date&time from one timezone to another.

Comment: SQL Server 2008. Generally I know how to convert one particular field. What I want is to be able to use SELECT * INTO .... I would like to avoid converting all fields, one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on SQL Server 2008, you could use the built-in functionality of the [`DATETIMEOFFSET` datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx), and the `SWITCHOFFSET` function.

You could do something like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTargetTable( ...... )
   SELECT
        SWITCHOFFSET(TODATETIMEOFFSET(YourSourceTime, '+04:00'), '-09:00'),
       .......
```

`TODATETIMEOFFSET` converts your "regular" date without any timezone information into a `DATETIMEOFFSET` type with a time zone (of your source location), and then you can apply a `SWITCHOFFSET` call to that value to "switch" your date/time to your target location's time zone.

This can be done in the scope of the `INSERT....SELECT` statement - no separate "row-by-row" updating necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be helpful, please follow the link:

[Effectively Converting dates between UTC and Local (ie. PST) time in SQL 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797/effectively-converting-dates-between-utc-and-local-ie-pst-time-in-sql-2005#25073)

Shortly, you do need to build time zone and DST tables to get some help with time zones.

Thanks