# How to show date time in CET format in text box in SSRS?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, timestamp

I have a report in SSRS , where i want to show date time in text box in CET? How to do this?

Comment: Does CET mean "Central European Time"? Does the original date time field have a timezone setting? Are you getting the original date time field from a SQLServer database?

Comment: Yes CET is Central European time. I was using expression in text box as =Now (format- dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz) this format is giving output in this form 26-Mar-2012 01:02:03 + 05:30.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS doesn't support timezones (beyond formatting datetime strings to include the timezone), although the accepted answer on [this MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/84710499-e0da-49b1-adaf-4d440c1b041c/) suggests changing the timezone on your reporting machine as a workaround.

If your report is retrieving its data from a SQLServer database, then the accepted answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797/effectively-converting-dates-between-utc-and-local-ie-pst-time-in-sql-2005) may help you to convert between timezones.

If your report is retrieving its data from a different RDBMS, then the database may offer greater inbuilt support for timezone functionality.