# SQL convert datetime and subtract hours

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to convert a datetime (createTime) field from its default 2012-10-06 02:29:37.243 format to am/pm so I use

```
convert(varchar, CreateTime, 100) as CreateTime
```

and get **Oct  6 2012  4:29AM**.

So far so good but in the same statement I want to subtract 4 hours and then display the field (GMT issues).

I have gone through some posts here but could not find anything that can do it in single statement.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
declare @createTime datetime = '2012-10-06 02:29:37.243';

-- original value, default formatting
select @createTime;

-- formatted
select convert(varchar, @createTime, 100);

-- subtract 4 hours, formatted
select convert(varchar, dateadd(hour, -4, @createTime), 100);
```

The query above that uses `dateadd` will always subtract 4 hours.  If your goal is to convert an arbitrary datetime from UTC to local time, then it's more complicated because the offset that you need to add/subtract depends on the original datetime.  A single value like -4 won't always work.  Here are some ideas for dealing with the general case:

[Effectively Converting dates between UTC and Local (ie. PST) time in SQL 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797/effectively-converting-dates-between-utc-and-local-ie-pst-time-in-sql-2005)

Comment: Thanks, select convert(varchar, dateadd(hour, -4, @createTime), 100); did the trick

Answer (score 2):

For People Who wants to subtract days and  hours

```
    declare @createTime datetime = '2012-10-06 02:29:37.243';
select @createtime as originaltime, dateadd(day, -4, dateadd(hour,-1,@createtime))as minus4daysandhour
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL server you could use [datetimeoffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx)

For mysql use [CONVERT_TZ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function to convert to a different timeszone.