# Subtract hours in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having hours(06:42,9:30,..) in DB. I want to subtract the hours from 08:00

I tried the below query

```
Select totalhrsinside as hour,convert(varchar, dateadd(minute, -8, totalhrsinside), 100) as diff from table_name
```

But it does not work as expected

**Output should be**

```
hour    diff
06:42   -01:18 
09:30   01:30
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756769/sql-convert-datetime-and-subtract-hours#12756867

Comment: @M.Mimpen I tried this link already. It outputs the result with date value. My expectation is only hour. Please see my sample Output

Comment: How about this one then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114307/extracting-hours-from-a-datetime-sql-server-2005

Comment: Time is stored in `TIME` datatype or `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Its VARCHAR format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for the difference in time, not to subtract or add.

```
SELECT  Hours
,       CONCAT(
                    CASE WHEN SIGN(diff) = -1 THEN '-' END
                  , FORMAT(ABS(diff/60), '0#')
                  , ':'
                  , FORMAT(ABS(diff%60), '0#')
              ) diff
FROM    (
            SELECT  '6:42' Hours, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '8:00', '6:42') diff UNION ALL
            SELECT  '9:30' Hours, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '8:00', '9:30') diff 
        ) D
```

Result:

```
+-------+-------+
| Hours | diff  |
+-------+-------+
| 6:42  | -01:18 |
| 9:30  | 01:30  |
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: `SELECT CONCAT (FORMAT(diff / 60, '0#'), ':', FORMAT(ABS(diff % 60), '0#'))` will return with the padding of zero as per the OP's expected result `-01:18, 01:30`

Comment: There's a small bug in this solution, it will not display a negative sign when the diff is smaller than 1 hour. Maybe use something like this in the select `CONCAT(CASE WHEN SIGN(diff) = -1 THEN '-' END, ABS(diff/60), ':', ABS(diff%60))`

Answer (score 1):

Using a case to add a minus sign if the time is lower.

```sql
select 
totalhrsinside as [hour],  
concat(
  case when DateDiff(minute, '08:00', totalhrsinside) < 0 then '-' end, 
  left(dateadd(minute, abs(datediff(minute, '08:00', totalhrsinside)), cast('00:00' as time)), 5)
) as diff
from 
(
 select totalhrsinside 
 from (values 
 ('06:45'),
 ('08:00'),
 ('09:30')
 ) v(totalhrsinside)
) testvalues;
```

Returns:

```
06:45   -01:15
08:00   00:00
09:30   01:30
```