# check stored procedure: Convert a datetime of specific city of timezone to another

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create Stored Proc who converts a datetime of specific city of timezone to another  using this article: [Effectively Converting dates between UTC and Local (ie. PST) time in SQL 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797/effectively-converting-dates-between-utc-and-local-ie-pst-time-in-sql-2005)

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_TimeOfTimeZone]
    (
        @DateTimeFrom   datetime,
        @CityNameFrom   nvarchar(MAX),
        @CityNameTo     nvarchar(MAX),
        @ResultDate     datetime OUTPUT
    )

AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    Declare @Query nvarchar(1000)
    Declare @ParmDefinition nvarchar (500)

    SET @Query = N''
    SET @Query = @Query + N'SELECT tz.Offset, tz.TimeZoneID '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'FROM TimeZoneCity, TimeZones tz WITH (NOLOCK) '
    --SET @Query = @Query + N'INNER JOIN    TimeZones WITH (NOLOCK) ON TimeZoneCity.TimeZoneID = tz.TimeZoneID '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'LEFT JOIN   TimeZoneDaylightSavings WITH (NOLOCK) ON TimeZoneDaylightSavings.TimeZoneID = tz.TimeZoneID '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'    WHERE TimeZoneCity.CityName = @CityNameTo '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'    AND TimeZoneCity.TimeZoneID = tz.TimeZoneID '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'        AND @DateTimeFrom >= TimeZoneDaylightSavings.BeginDst AND @DateTimeFrom < TimeZoneDaylightSavings.EndDst '

    SET @Query = @Query + N'SET @ResultDate =   DATEADD(HH, tz.Offset + CASE WHEN tz.TimeZoneID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'                            DATEADD(HH, (SELECT TimeZones.Offset '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'                                            FROM TimeZones, TimeZoneCity WITH (NOLOCK) ' 
    SET @Query = @Query + N'                                            WHERE TimeZoneCity.CityName = @CityNameFrom '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'                                            AND TimeZoneCity.TimeZoneID = TimeZones.TimeZoneID), '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'                                    @DateTimeFrom)) '

    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@ResultDate datetime, @DateTimeFrom datetime, @CityNameFrom nvarchar(MAX), @CityNameTo nvarchar(MAX) '

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query, @ParmDefinition, @ResultDate = @ResultDate, @DateTimeFrom = @DateTimeFrom, @CityNameFrom = @CityNameFrom, @CityNameTo = @CityNameTo

    SET NOCOUNT OFF 
RETURN
```

When i execute it, i have these errors:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "tz.Offset" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "tz.TimeZoneID" could not be bound.
```

Can anybody check my stored procedure and help me? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing `JOIN` types in your query. The following line is joined using commas and a `WHERE` clause

```
FROM TimeZoneCity, TimeZones tz WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Since you are mixing the join syntax, the alias `tz` is not available.  You should the same syntax throughout. This line should be:

```
SET @Query = @Query + N'FROM TimeZoneCity 
                        INNER JOIN TimeZones tz WITH (NOLOCK) 
                              ON TimeZoneCity.TimeZoneID = tz.TimeZoneID'
```

Comment: Thanks bluefeet, this is a good point, but it did not solve my problem, I have the same error. Maybe second part of query is not correct??

Comment: If you remove the `SET @ResultDate` portion of your query does it work?

Comment: @Vinipuh It is not clear what you are trying to do with that second part of your query.