# SQL Convert time in seconds into a local time zone

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am working on query where time is stored in seconds.

Right now the string I have shows the following.

```
Select schema.table.OpenDate_Seconds, '19700101' as Open Date
```

That gets me the sever time for the Open. How can I adjust this to get Central Time?

Thanks in advance for looking and helping.

Comment: What's the server time zone?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Using SQL Server 2008 R2 .. Server is Pacific Time, want report in Central time.

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/24797/3660930