# What are the key difference between MySQL and MS SQL Language?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Differences Between MySql and MS SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616/differences-between-mysql-and-ms-sql)

What is the key difference between `MySQL` and `SQL Server` from the SQL language perspective. The reason why I am asking is that I need to quickly master some basic SQL knowledge and need to find a book to start with.

I find this one through amazon.com Learning SQL, 2nd Edition, however, this book is for `MySQL`. All other books for `MS SQL` are big one that cannot be finished in a short time.

So, it is fine I just grab a `MySQL` book and later I can easily transfer to `MS SQL` world or I should immediately go into `MS SQL Server`?

// update the title based on the comments ///

Comment: Well what's the different between GCC and the C or C++ standards? Extensions, sometimes missing pieces, etc.

Comment: Once you become comfortable with MySQL it will be pretty easy to transition to MsSQL. If all you plan on using is MsSQL though, might as well start there.

Comment: It seemed clear to me that you meant "what is the difference between MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server" as opposed to asking how MySQL deviates from the SQL language. If this is not the case, please reverse my edits. For your reference, Microsoft's database product is called "Microsoft SQL Server" or "SQL Server", and you should refer to it as such to avoid confusion.

Comment: Learn MySQL, then learn MS SQL: that will give you a feel of the differences between databases and a broader perspective on the field. Just don't speak to your colleagues about SQL starting every sentence with "ah, but in MySQL..."

Comment: MySQL doesn't have ROW_NUMBER() and friends - which makes a lot of queries painful!

Comment: @q0987, Migrating from MySQL to MSSQL will give you lots and lots of headaches. Better to start with PostgreSQL easier path to MSSQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following links might help you out.

Note that the two are very different.
If you want to make your live easy, use PostgreSQL, the gap between **that** and SQL-server is much smaller.

**Difference between MySQL and MSSQL**

**From microsoft and mysql respectively:**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966396.aspx
http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql_wp_mssql2mysql.php (login required sorry)

On stackoverflow: [Differences between MySQL and SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616/differences-between-mysql-and-ms-sql)

**Difference between PostgreSQL and MySQL**

http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL

**Difference between postgreSQL and MSSQL**

On SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907908/postgres-to-sql-server
and: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630891/tips-for-sql-server-developer-picking-up-postgresql

**Diff between all three :-)**
http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/51-Cross-Compare-of-SQL-Server,-MySQL,-and-PostgreSQL.html
or http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/

Comment: It depends which parts of the MySQL "feature" set you use; if you set the options to require strictness, then it's much closer to the standard.  If you use backticks around names and double quotes around strings, it's always going to be difficult :-/

Comment: I tend to agree about Postgres though; it gives you far fewer ways to shoot yourself in the foot, in regards to standards compliance and in general.

Comment: @El Yobo, backticks and double quotes are the least of your worries. What about the fact that `group by` can be added to any query in MySQL but will generate errors in almost all other SQL flavors in many cases.

Comment: Yeah, MySQL's group by is certainly weird, but probably less common in your queries than using strings (and therefore quotes) :)

Comment: @El Yobo, you're missing the point. The quotes issue is a simple search and replace. Other issues of which the `group by` is just an example will require hours and hours of debugging and rethinking.

Comment: Searching for group by statements is probably easier than searching for quotes, given that your code will almost certainly contain many quotes in non-SQL contexts and few, if any, `group by`s in non-SQL contexts.  Other subtle differences are likely to exist between any given pair of RDBMSs, I'm not sure that (aside from these obvious issues) Postgres is better than MySQL in this regard.  Did you have some documentation which suggests this?  In my personal experience I've found that most SQL works on MySQL, Postgres and MSSQL.

Comment: Your answer is outdated by now (2017), but one of the links you provided was already outdated when you posted it: the technet link is to a 2001 article, which was already 10 years old when you posted your answer and contains VERY outdated information!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good tutorial to start with SQL - http://philip.greenspun.com/sql/ (rather old, but valid) - though it points more to Oracle, but MySQL is mentioned there.