# How can I connect/run Joomla on Mac (or Linux) to/with a remote Microsoft SQL server?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, joomla, pdo, joomla2.5

I am starting a project in Joomla. Web server is Apache on Mac.

The database I would like to run on is a remote Microsoft SQL server. I am only given the option of installing with mysql when I hit the install page.

Microsoft provides PHP drivers, but they are Windows only.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Are there any other options?

Comment: Been a long time since I've done this, but I believe unixODBC with FreeTDS will be your best bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work, MS SQL is not supported by Joomla at this time. The problem you will run in to is that they have very different implementations of SQL syntax. Basically, the queries used for MySQL don't necessarily work in MSSQL. You would need to rewrite all of the queries in the Joomla framework to use MSSQL syntax, which would be a tremendous undertaking and would make it near impossible to add extensions or Joomla updates.

More info here - [Differences between MySQL and SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616/differences-between-mysql-and-ms-sql)

Comment: I have switched to CodeIgniter, whose built-in query-builder does exactly what you describe. I was up and running, connected to SQL Server from a Mac in under 30.